# How to Pass Laravel API data to the Angular inputs coming from One to Many Relationship

Tags: php, angular, laravel, eloquent

I have one to many relationship in Laravel API with Employee and Salary Models like this
Employee.php

```
protected $fillable = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name','gender','hire_date'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';

     public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no','emp_no');
    }
```

Salary.php

```
protected $fillable = ['salary','from_date','to_date'];

    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

I have following Angular Data Insert form for both Models

```
<div class="detail-list">
    <h3>Employee Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="insertData()">
        <h4>Profile Detail</h4>
        
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.first_name">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.last_name">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="birth_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" name="birth_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.birth_date">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="hire_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Hire Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" name="hire_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.hire_date">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     
     <h4>Salary Details</h4>
     
     <div class="salary-details"  >
       <div class="table">
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="salary" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Salary</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.salary">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">From Date</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="date" name="from_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.from_date">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="to_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">To Date</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.to_date">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
       </div>
     </div>
    
      
    <br>
    <button  class="btn btn-dark btn-sm mt-4 btnPosition">Add Employee</button>
    <br><br>
    </form>
```

in the form salary data insert section `<input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.salary">` unable to pass form input data to the model console encountered following error msg `ERROR TypeError: ctx.salary is undefined` I think problem is backend relationship unable to identify in frontend side. but when I use API like postman it is working fine. problems with Angular side? how could I fix this problem here?

**Updated**
My Employee Component
employee.ts

```
export class Employee {
    birth_date:any;
    first_name:any;
    last_name:any;
    gender:any;
    hire_date:any;
salaries: any;
titles:any;
salary:any;
title:any;
emp_no: any;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77510706/how-to-bind-laravel-model-relationship-with-angular-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind Laravel Model Relationship with Angular Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77510706/how-to-bind-laravel-model-relationship-with-angular-form)

Comment: Have you properly initialized salary object , in your component class ? because  in backend side your are using method salaries(), it it right ?

Comment: @Akshayak did you mean Angular side component class?

Comment: yes angular side

Comment: @Akshayak please see my Updates question I have put my component here

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Salary {
    salary: any;
    from_date: any;
    to_date: any;
}

export class Employee {
    birth_date: any;
    first_name: any;
    last_name: any;
    gender: any;
    hire_date: any;
    salaries: Salary[] = []; // Array of Salary objects
}
```

Binding nested props

```
  <form>
    <div *ngFor="let salary of employee.salaries; let i = index">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="salary" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Salary {{ i + 1 }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="salary{{ i }}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.salaries[i].salary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">From Date {{ i + 1 }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="date" name="from_date{{ i }}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.salaries[i].from_date">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="to_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">To Date {{ i + 1 }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="date" name="to_date{{ i }}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.salaries[i].to_date">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Other input fields for other salary details -->
        <hr> <!-- Optional: Add a horizontal line between each employee's salary block -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: could I use `*ngFor="let salary of employee.salaries"` for data insert normaly it is use data loop

Comment: yes you can use ,i have edited the code please check

Comment: in this way my salary inputs did not display here